# Have leftover items placed in new row

Tags: php

So I am able to display 3 items per row in a webpage. However, the problem arises if there is an extra item. Say I have an array with items `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11`. I am able to display items 1 to 9. But unable to display `10` and `11` due to an index error, if I add `12`, it will all be fine.

What I want is to display from this.

```
<div class='row-0'>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
</div>
<div class='row-1'>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
</div>
<div class='row-2'>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
</div>
```

To this:

```
<div class='row-0'>
<p>1</p>
<p>2</p>
<p>3</p>
</div>
<div class='row-1'>
<p>4</p>
<p>5</p>
<p>6</p>
</div>
<div class='row-2'>
<p>7</p>
<p>8</p>
<p>9</p>
</div>
<div class='row-3'>
<p>10</p>
<p>11</p>
</div>
```

Here is my demo code so far:

```
<?php

$arr = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10);

$row=0;
$i=0;

while(true){
    echo "<div class='row-".$row."'>\n";
    while(true){
        echo "<p>".$arr[$i]."</p>\n";
        $i++;
        if($i%3===0){
            break;
        }
    }
    echo "</div>\n";
    $row++;
    if($arr[$i]==count($arr)){
        break;
    }
}
?>
```

Any tips? Thank you for reading.

Comment: no need for two while loops, just use a for loop and use the modulo concept to close the div and start a new one

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split array into a specific number of chunks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15723059/split-array-into-a-specific-number-of-chunks)

Answer (score 0):

You should just check inside the array.
And use 2 loops.
The first loop for the number of rows.
The second loop for the amount of elements and whether they exist in the array.

```
<?php

$numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11);
$number_of_rows = ceil(count($numbers) / 3);

$counter = 0;


for($i = 0 ; $i < $number_of_rows; $i++){
    echo "<div class='row-".($i)."'>\n";
        for($item = 3; $item > 0; $item--){
            if(array_key_exists($counter , $numbers)){
                echo "<p>".$numbers[$counter]."</p>\n";
            }
            $counter++;
        }
    echo "</div>\n";
}

?>
```